# display: inline-block; divs behaving erratically

Tags: css, html

I have a main div, and three divs inside of it. They are all given a width 30%, and they are all centered within the main div.

I used display: inline-block; so that the three divs appear next to each other, but when I give them a height of anything, the two left-most go down a bit, and the right one stays where it should. All that's inside the divs is just simple inputs, nothing that could dynamically increase the div's size.

How should I fix this?

Comment: Could you provide the html/css as well?

Comment: It would be good if you could show us an example here. Or at least the code involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. the three inside divs must be floated to the left so that they should align exactly. without floating, they can create problems in different browsers.

CSS Code

```
#wrapper { width: 100%; height: auto; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
.inner { width: 30%; float:left; min-height:50px; margin:0 5px 0 0;}
```

HTML Code

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <div class="inner"></div>
   <div class="inner"></div>
   <div class="inner" style=" margin:0;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It isn't a "must" to float those divs, this can of course be done with `display:inline-block;` as well, keeping in mind to vertically position them with `vertical-align` and keeping track of white-space - actually using floats does more often than not create problems for the newer frontender

Comment: I had same problem. This answer, `Float: left;`, did make them align for me, so "it worked". But I gave my vote to `vertical-align: top` because it also worked, and it communicates better what I wanted to achieve, rather than side effect of float left (that seemed kind of magic to me).

Answer (score 2):

It's quite hard to work out the issue without any live code but give these a go. For the DIVs inside the main DIV, assign the class `vertical-align:top`

Another option (or as well as) is to set the `line-height` to the desired height rather than the `height`.

If you have no luck with these, I suggest you put your html and css up on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working solution. http://jsfiddle.net/j3zjg/

```
<style>
#container{
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    border:1px solid red;
}

#container div{
    width:30%;
    float:left;
    height:40px;
    background:red;
    margin-right:5px;
}
</style>

<div id="container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```